# Can I use an Image variable in a Mouse method instead of specific x- and y-values? [Might be Slick2D only]

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, lwjgl, slick2d

I've been creating an app to help me understand Java more and one of the things I coded is the ability to change settings (resolution, music loudness, fps limit etc...) to values (1280x720, 0-10, VSync). I've drawn images in photoshop and added them in the class files, gave them a place in the code so they get rendered on the screen.

```
if((xpos>400 && xpos<600) && (ypos>255 && ypos<305)){
    if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
```

This is the part of the code that matters, currently I have to manually search for the boundaries of the images and with some simple math I figure out the coordinates which I need to use, but I designed the music loudness so that it would have 11 seperate images, one for each value (0-10). Is there a simpler way to let Java know that "if the cursor is over the image, do this" or am I doomed to code in the seperate coordinates 11 times (and probably more times for other settings.

Please let me know if there's a better way of doing this!

Thanks.

P.S. I can't seem to find how to draw a drop-down menu with Slick2D and LWJGL. Can I still use the standard Java code to draw a drop-down menu or should I look for a library such as Swing to do the job for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an `ImageHolder` class that can hold and draw an `Image`, and save the position it is drawn at. For instance, it can have the same `draw(float x, float y)` method of the Image, but additionally save the x and y coordinate and make them available through `getX()` and `getY()` methods.

Put all your `ImageHolders` into a `Collection` you can iterate, and put the code for mouse detection into a loop that iterates said `Collection`. For instance:

```
for (ImageHolder ih : imageHolderList) {
    if (input.isMousePressed(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)) {
        if (mouseX >= ih.getX() && mouseX < (ih.getX() + ih.getWidth())
                && mouseY >= ih.getY() && mouseY < (ih.getX() + ih.getWidth())) {
            doSomething();
    }
}
```

Generally, if you have duplicated code in your program, there is a way to make some of it go away with abstraction.

Edit: As for your last question, Slick2D and LWJGL are for high performance. OpenGL is used to draw the images by using the GPU.
Swing on the other hand is used for it's convenience for building advanced GUIs. It comes with a lot of neat abstractions and can make all sorts of fancy things. However, it is considerably slower than Slick2D.

If you need the speed of Slick2D, and in turn LWJGL on top of OpenGL, know that it comes at a cost. The G in LWJGL stands Gaming, because it's made for gaming and not GUI programming. You can get a lot of the functionality of Swing in Slick2D, with tools like [TWL](http://l33tlabs.org/) and [Nifty-Gui](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/), but they have vastly less documentation and example code than Swing. That being said, if you are fearless, give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what kind of application you're writing. Resolution? Music loudness? FPS limit? Those are not standard things in java, sounds like you're making a full-screen game or something.

Also what are you doing with the images and the mouse? From your code, it looks like you're trying to detect a click within a certain area (probably where an image is supposed to be displayed), but you didn't explain anything in your question.

Anyway, if you're using Swing (which is "standard Java code" for GUIs), then you can display images using components (such as JLabel) and handle clicks on a component directly rather than checking coordinates. Swing also handles drop-down and pop-up menus.
If you're using some other stuff such as opengl, then... perhaps somebody else can help you.

Comment: I'm a beginner here still learning certain methods (the Javadoc doesn't explain in what situation I should use it, it only gives me the code). It's really just for personal experience, but to make things simpler let's assume I'm making a game.
The images are used for changing the sound level (music loudness). Imagine there are 11 identical images placed next to eachother with each image having a sound level from 0-10 (I know there are other ways to do this such as adding and substracting). My question is if I can detect the entire image instead of having to put in coordinates manually.

Comment: Learning what? The javadoc of what? It doesn't explain when you should use what? You're making a game (or some other thing) using what? It seems like you're trying very hard not to provide any useful information :)

Comment: I messed up, pressing enter instead of shift-enter :<

Comment: It's ok, my answer still stands (and the subsequent questions too)

Comment: Javadocs in general don't really explain in what situation I should a method, so my point with that is that I already looked at the Javadoc but didn't get any wiser of it.
Comments inc.

Comment: I'm pretty much discovering Java, for the sake of understanding I'll make a game. I'm trying to learn the methods so I know what/why/how they do/work and when to use them. Javadoc gives me the code of a method such as [link](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/state/transition/Transition.html) , but I'm having trouble figuring out how to even use certain methods and in what case I can use them. With the game I'm making, how am I supposed to know in what class I'm supposed to put a method/constructor. Should I put it in the main class, or in a class of let's say the menu?

Comment: I'm making a game using Slick2D LWJGL, Artemis and all the audio jazz such as jorbis and tritonus. Currently I want to know **if it's possible for the [Mouse](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/gui/MouseOverArea.html) to detect images rather than only coordinates.**

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If you're new to java then I think it's way too early to use 3rd party libraries such as Slick2D. Just stick with the standard library first, until you get some experience. As for the specifics of Slick2D, I have no idea because I never used it (maybe somebody else can answer). I told you how it can be done with Swing.

Comment: Like, is there a method that replaces if((xpos>428 && xpos<573) && (ypos>336 && ypos<374)){ with something like if(Mouse.something = image1){ ?

Unexisting example = if(Mouse.isOverArea(image1)){

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help, I'll look into Swing, I guess I'm too impatient with this haha.